# Group by error in my MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to show the amount of purchases grouped by ONLY city. But I want to show the result in this way: city -> state -> amount. Just like this:

```
Alabama Birmingham 80
Alabama Montgomery 100
```

So I write this query:

```
select state, city, count(*) from address 
inner join person inner join purchase
where purchase.person_FK = person.id and address.person_FK = person.id
group by city
order by state, city;
```

But then I got this error: "Error code : 1055. Expression #1 of SELECT list is not on group by clause and contains nonaggregate column 'v2.address.state' witch is not functionally depend on columns in group by clause this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

Can you guys help me?

Comment: why don't you want to group by `state` when you obviously need to group by `state`? if you do not group by `state`, then what happens to Montgomery, Massachusetts; Montgomery, Minnesota; and Montgomery, Vermont ?

Comment: What? I want to group by city, not state

Comment: You want to group by `city` **and** `state` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by - and `order by state, city, count(*)`

Comment: You should really put your join conditions in ON clauses.

Comment: What about Birmingham, Michigan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group by` both.

```
select state, city, count(*) from address 
inner join person inner join purchase
where purchase.person_FK = person.id and address.person_FK = person.id
group by state, city
order by state, city;
```

Comment: Thanks man! It worked.... But can you explain me why I have to do this?

Comment: @flpn You have to `group by` columns you aren't aggregating. The only other choice would be to aggregate `state` with `max()` or `min()` or something, and that is a bad choice because you will be adding multiple states purchases all into one.

Comment: I had the same problem with an order by command in other query. I want to show name -> amount -> totalprice, ordered by price. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same city name in multiple states, therefore you must group by the state as well, otherwise mysql cannot decide which state to display next to the city name.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you just group by state and city. This is completely fine, because city fully depends on the state.

To answer the more general question behind this, let me show a more advanced example.

Imagine you have two tables:

table1 (dimension, value)

table2 (dimension, moreinfo1, moreinfo2, ..., moreinfon)

Then you don't want to have something like `group by dimension, moreinfo1, moreinfo2, ...`.

The solutíon is to put the aggregation into a CTE and join afterwards:

```
with aggr as (
  select dimension, avg(value)
  from table1
  group by dimension
)
select *
from aggr join table2 using (dimension)
```

If you don't have a using clause in your SQL dialect, just use whatever is common in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

By far everyones suggestions about `Group By state, city` IS in fact correct.

but to answer your question, in MySQL 5.7+  SQL Mode "only_full_group_by" is turned on by default.. What this means is if you are going to group your results together, ALL fields you choose to display in your SELECT statement must be of some aggregated result.  Eg. SUM(), MAX(), MIN(), COUNT(), ect...

In your case "state" is being left as a standard result.. Which in short means you have no guarantee on what result you will get in your "state" column.. you could get Massachusetts OR Minnesota as pointed out above.

All that being said, if you STILL want to NOT get that error, use the following to disable this SQL mode.

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

This will removed the set sql mode for the duration of your current MySQL connection.

**Advisory:**

This will be helpful for testing.. but if your query doesn't work with  only_full_group_by ON, odds are VERY high you're doing something you don't want done.